# Why do some routers not have a WAN port?

Tags: router, home-networking, modem

I have a ZyXEL P-870H-5xA v2 VDSL2 modem to act as a modem, but it's not wireless, so I figured I'd grab a wireless router to to connect to it to act as the wireless router.

A friend had a TP-LINK TD-W8960N modem router lying around, I did a quick google, it looked OK, so I accepted it.

I get the router, and lo and behold, it doesn't have a WAN ethernet port, so there's no way to connect it via ethernet to the ZyXEL modem.

Why do some routers not have a WAN port? Is this just a 'being a cheap router' type thing?

Is there anyway to connect it to the modem via the 'Line' port (ie that smaller phone cable port).

Comment: It has a WAN port, it's just internally connected to the internal output port of the modem.

Comment: Disable the DHCP server (if any) on the TP-Link router, take a patch cable from your DSL "modem" and plug it into one of the ports of the TP-Link. You're now using that device as a Wireless Access Point (see if the TP-Link has the "Wireless Access Point" option in their web GUI)

Comment: *"Is this just a 'being a cheap router' type thing?"* -- Almost all consumer-grade equipment is "cheap" in comparison to industrial equipment.  It's a unit of average consumer-grade quality and level of functionality.  It has a high-degree of integration; it incorporates four individual units: an ADSL modem, a router, a wireless access point and a switch.  You erred by not knowing that you need a VDSL2 modem and the TD-W8960N was an incompatible ADSL2 modem.  It is still usable though, as JSanchez mentions above.

Comment: @sawdust - I knew that I needed a VDSL2 modem, which is why I bought the ZyXEL modem. The problem was not realising that I couldn't use the TP-LINK as a wireless access point.

Comment: *"The problem was not realising that I couldn't use the TP-LINK as a wireless access point."* -- But you can use the TP-Link as a wireless access point.  You simply don't use its WAN port, because that could introduce a second (unnecessary) router and another layer of NAT & DHCP.

Comment: @sawdust - So how would I use it as a wireless access point?

Comment: One more time: read JSanchez's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That unit *does* have a WAN port. It's just that its WAN port is for a DSL connection, not for Ethernet.

As its "modem router" name implies, it has a DSL modem built in. Unfortunately for you, that particular unit has an ADSL2+ modem, which is slower than VDSL2, so it's not a drop-in replacement for your ZyXEL P-870H-5xA v2 VDSL2 modem.

Comment: That's right, I'm wanting to use the TP-LINK router for wireless routing only. Would it be possible to use a RJ11 to RJ45 cable to connect the ZyXEL modem to the TP-LINK router, without losing speed?

Comment: @user1068446 No. Your ZyXEL modem's LAN port is a technology called Ethernet, which is a completely different thing from your TP-Link's WAN port, which is a technology called DSL. The other end of a DSL link is called a DSLAM. It's a very expensive multi-port DSL modem/router installed at your telephone company's central office, that serves hundreds of customers.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. So to answer the question - is it just that this kind of modem router is a cheap 'single use in mind' consumer model?

Comment: @user1068446 Do you want to use it for routing or as an access point? Your statements seem inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use this device as a wireless router only.
The TP-LINK TD-W8960N allows a LAN (ethernet) port to be configured as a WAN port.
See http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=344